# Drawing a simple circle on the UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

When the view loads in my iOS application, I dynamically create a UIImageView and place my Image inside of it.  I would like to draw a simple circle on top of the UIImageView, but have been unable to do so thus far.

I wrote this code and attempted to draw a circle upon recieving an event from another object...

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 255, 0.5);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

...but <strike>nothing happens</strike> I receive an error.

```
<Error>: CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
```

I'm attempting to draw above everything, to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just curious, @George, why [was this deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5683492/revisions) for some time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> attempted to draw a circle **upon recieving an event** from another object. *[emphasis mine]*

Your `CGContextRef` is `NULL` because there is no graphics context in the place that you are calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`.

When you're in the `drawRect:` of a view, a context has already been set up for you, so you can draw and can get the current context if you need to. In an arbitrary method (such as an `IBAction`) however, there may not be a graphics context for you to draw into. You need to either create one, using perhaps [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions), or (preferably) just set a flag in your event handler method to indicate that something extra should be drawn the next time through `drawRect:`, and then call `setNeedsDisplay`.